# Replacing punctuations and double quotations

Tags: javascript, html, web, dreamweaver

Please have a look at the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script>
    //Function to Trim
String.prototype.trim = function()
{
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
};

//Function to remove punctuation
function replaceAll(find, replace, str) {
   return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
}


function count()
{
    var listOfWords, paragraph, listOfWordsArray, paragraphArray;
    var wordCounter=0;

    listOfWords = document.getElementById("wordsList").value.trim();
    listOfWords = listOfWords.toUpperCase();


    //Split the words
    listOfWordsArray = listOfWords.split(/\r?\n/);



    //Get the paragrah text
    paragraph = document.getElementById("paragraph").value.trim();;
    paragraph = paragraph.toUpperCase();


    //Filter all the punctuations
    replaceAll("\"","",paragraph);
    replaceAll("[","",paragraph);
    replaceAll("]","",paragraph);
    replaceAll("{","",paragraph);
    replaceAll("}","",paragraph);
    replaceAll("(","",paragraph);
    replaceAll(")","",paragraph);
    replaceAll("<","",paragraph);
    replaceAll(">","",paragraph);
    replaceAll(":","",paragraph);
    replaceAll(",","",paragraph);
    replaceAll("-","",paragraph);
    replaceAll("...","",paragraph);
    replaceAll("!","",paragraph);
    replaceAll("<<","",paragraph);
    replaceAll(">>","",paragraph);
    replaceAll("","",paragraph);
    replaceAll(".","",paragraph);
    replaceAll("?","",paragraph);
    replaceAll("/","",paragraph);
    replaceAll("\\","",paragraph);



    paragraphArray = paragraph.split(" ");


    //check whether paragraph contains words in list
    for(var i=0; i<paragraphArray.length; i++)
    {

        //re = new RegExp("\\b"+paragraphArray[i]+"\\b","i");

        if (listOfWordsArray.indexOf(paragraphArray[i]) >= 0) 
        {

        }
        else
            {
                wordCounter++;
            }
    }

    var average =0;
    average = (wordCounter/paragraphArray.length)*100;
    average = 100-average;
    average = Math.round(average*100)/100;


    window.alert("Number of Words: "+paragraphArray.length+ "\n"+ "Number of Unmatched words: "+wordCounter+ "\n"+ "Percentage "+average+"%" );
}
</script>

</head>


<body>
<center>
<p> Enter your Word List here </p>
<br />
<textarea id="wordsList" cols="100" rows="10"></textarea>

<br />
<p>Enter your paragraph here</p>
<textarea id="paragraph" cols="100" rows="15"></textarea>

<br />
<br />
<button id="btn1"  onclick="count()">Calculate Percentage</button>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

In here, I am trying to remove all the punctuation from the text. But my code gives no output. My knowledge lacks when it comes to web scripting languages, so I can't find the solution. How can I remove the punctuation from the text? What am I doing wrong here?

**Update**

According to Rahul's answer, I edited my code in the following way, but unfortunately still I have no good. I want to remove all the punctuation from the entire text, not just remove the first punctuation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script>
    //Function to Trim
String.prototype.trim = function()
{
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
};

//Function to remove punctuation
function replaceAll(find, replace, str) {
   return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
}


function count()
{
    var listOfWords, paragraph, listOfWordsArray, paragraphArray;
    var wordCounter=0;

    listOfWords = document.getElementById("wordsList").value.trim();
    listOfWords = listOfWords.toUpperCase();


    //Split the words
    listOfWordsArray = listOfWords.split(/\r?\n/);



    //Get the paragrah text
    paragraph = document.getElementById("paragraph").value.trim();;
    paragraph = paragraph.toUpperCase();


    //Filter all the punctuations
    var newstring= paragraph.replace(/[\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g,"");
    var finalString = newstring.replace(/\s{2,}/g," ");



    paragraphArray = finalString.split(" ");


    //check whether paragraph contains words in list
    for(var i=0; i<paragraphArray.length; i++)
    {

        //re = new RegExp("\\b"+paragraphArray[i]+"\\b","i");

        if (listOfWordsArray.indexOf(paragraphArray[i]) >= 0) 
        {

        }
        else
            {
                wordCounter++;
            }
    }

    var average =0;
    average = (wordCounter/paragraphArray.length)*100;
    average = 100-average;
    average = Math.round(average*100)/100;


    window.alert("Number of Words: "+paragraphArray.length+ "\n"+ "Number of Unmatched words: "+wordCounter+ "\n"+ "Percentage "+average+"%" );
}
</script>

</head>


<body>
<center>
<p> Enter your Word List here </p>
<br />
<textarea id="wordsList" cols="100" rows="10"></textarea>

<br />
<p>Enter your paragraph here</p>
<textarea id="paragraph" cols="100" rows="15"></textarea>

<br />
<br />
<button id="btn1"  onclick="count()">Calculate Percentage</button>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try like  this:-

```
var s = "Your%^%*^%^&*^% string '"+"'which*^&^&( consists of punctuation";
var st = s.replace(/["']/g, "")
var newstring= st.replace(/[\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`"~()]/g,"");
var finalString = newstring.replace(/\s{2,}/g," ");
alert(finalString);
```

The above code will replace all the punctuation from your string `s`

The above code works fine. Please check the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eTvpn/1/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but still there is no good. I have updated the code with your solution, please have a look

Comment: @Artificial_Intelligence:- I have updated my answer with the JSFiddle of my code which is working fine!!

Comment: I found the issue. This is not dealing with quotation marks. How can I remove double quotation marks?

Comment: @Artificial_Intelligence:- You need **.replace(/["']/g, "");** to remove the double quotes